# На JS сделать выбор марки ТС

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

Использую django; Необходимо получить значение BMW, скрипт при выборе показывает значение value=1, а небходимо BMW, что нужно поправить?

```js
document.getElementById("marka-select").onchange = function(evt) {
  var marka = evt.target.value;
  console.log(marka)
};
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="mb-3" id="marka-select">
      <select name="&lt;class &#x27;auto.models.Car&#x27;&gt;-marka" class="form-control" placeholder="Марка" id="id_&lt;class &#x27;auto.models.Car&#x27;&gt;-marka">
        <option value="" selected>---------</option>

        <option value="1">BMW</option>

        <option value="2">Lexus</option>

        <option value="3">Audi</option>

        <option value="4">Mazda</option>

      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: `{{ autoform.marka }}` это у вас что за HTML элемент?

Answer (score 0):

> Необходимо получить значение BMW, скрипт при выборе показывает значение value=1, а небходимо BMW, что нужно поправить?

Предложу такой вариант...

```js
document.getElementById("marka-select").onchange = function(evt) {
  const o = evt.target
  var marka = o.options[o.selectedIndex].textContent;
  console.log(marka)
};
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="mb-3" id="marka-select">
      <select name="&lt;class &#x27;auto.models.Car&#x27;&gt;-marka" class="form-control" placeholder="Марка" id="id_&lt;class &#x27;auto.models.Car&#x27;&gt;-marka">
        <option value="" selected>---------</option>

        <option value="1">BMW</option>

        <option value="2">Lexus</option>

        <option value="3">Audi</option>

        <option value="4">Mazda</option>

      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
```